# Umbraco ucommerce - Checkout pipeline not executing automatically after DIBS payment callback

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I am facing exactly similer issue as [this issue](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ucommerce/ucommerce-support/14331-Integration-with-payment-%28Dibs-in-my-case%29?p=0),(I am using DIBS test card). I checked all relative posts but somehow could not solve it. I did all the configuration suggested in www.publicvoid.dk/...ludeDIBSAsAPaymentMethod.aspx. Also selected "Checkout" pipeline to execute. I am being redirected to Payment page when I call Library.CreatePayment(PaymentMethodId) and after successful payment I am redirected back to successUrl (confirmation page in my case). But still "Checkout" pipeline is not executed after payment callback, my basket is not cleared. My payment status is "Pending authorization" (in payment_status table) which is not changing to acquired.

Here is my config :

```
testMode="True"

debug="False"

login="*********"

password="*****************"

callbackUrl="(auto)"

acceptUrl="http://localhost:13267/en-us/paymentconfirmation.aspx"

cancelUrl="http://localhost:13267/en-us/productoverview.aspx"

merchant="90151341"

useMd5="False"

key1="******************************************************"

key2="******************************************************" />
```

And after successful payment following parameters are returned :

```
merchant +" --->"+ *******
test +" --->"+ 1 
decorator +" --->"+ default 
callbackurl +" --->"+ http://localhost:13267/9/26/PaymentProcessor.axd 
lang +" --->"+ en 
currency +" --->"+ EUR 
amount +" --->"+ 291300 
submitBasket +" --->"+ yes 
orderGuid +" --->"+ 18a76c1a-4169-47e3-a317-175402d869e0 
paytype +" --->"+ V-DK 
flexwin_cardlogosize +" --->"+ 1 
orderid +" --->"+ Reference-52 
accepturl +" --->"+ http://localhost:13267/en-us/paymentconfirmation.aspx 
cancelurl +" --->"+ http://localhost:13267/en-us/productoverview.aspx 
transact +" --->"+ 727162826 
cardnomask +" --->"+ XXXXXXXXXXXX0000 
approvalcode +" --->"+ 123456 
statuscode +" --->"+ 2
```

Am I missing any part of configuration? Or what could be problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted an answer at http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ucommerce/ucommerce-support/41201-Checkout-pipeline-not-executing-automatically-after-DIBS-payment-callback

Please refer to that to keep the conversation in a single place.

Thanks.